# Sorting numbers and strings together, where strings are numbers that can be followed by letters

Tags: excel, sorting

I need to sort an Excel sheet which has a mixture of actual numbers and text containing numbers possibly followed by text.
For example if the following list was randomised, the end result should be:

```
54 <-- Actual number
55
56
57
57B <-- Number followed by a letter
57M <-- Yet another letter
58
58M
59
59M
60
60B
61
61M
62
62B
63
64
65
66
90
99
99A
100
100B
100B2
120
120B
```

I tried a million different ways. However, I can't work out a way to sort the sheet like this.

Is there a way to do this? Some sort of "humanised" sorting?

Comment: FINGER ITCHING TO CLOSE IT? This is not something that is doable by a "power user", I think this will require some kind of macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a helper column with the following formula:

```
=TEXT(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))))-1),A1),"000")&IFERROR(MID(A1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))),LEN(A1)),"")
```

Then sort on that.

Note: Change the `"000"` to the same number of digits as the largest number in the list.

Also if one does not have SEQUENCE substitute that part with `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))`  The formula would then also need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Sorted on Column A:

[image]

Sorted on Column B:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is great and amazing but... why does it work?!?!?

Comment: Oh wait, I spoke to soon. I updated the answer -- your trick dies when a three digit number enters the equation...

Comment: I updated the question, I am very sorry for not including the three digits to start with

Comment: @Merc see edit.  As to why.  Excel will always put numbers first and text second in sorting so we need to make them all text and the prefix numbers must all have the same number of digits because sorting text is character by character.